# How to summarize an integer array for each index?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

How do I effectively summarize/aggregate these arrays in postgresql, given that I e.g. want to summarize all integers from index 2 to index 6, on column `counts` and COALESCE null or missing to 0?

```
table_x:

ID       Counts
1        {1,    2,   null,  0,    null,   5,   8,   10}
2        {2,    5,   1,     null, 3}
3        {null, 3,   5,     0,    null,   8,   1}

To result:

Counts
{10,6,0,3,13}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) to get each element, filter indexes from 2 to 6, calculate sum per each position and combine everything to one array using `array_agg`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT pos, SUM(val::int) AS val
   FROM table_x
   ,LATERAL unnest(counts,ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) 
    AS sub(val, pos)
   WHERE pos BETWEEN 2 AND 6
   GROUP BY pos
)
SELECT array_agg(val ORDER BY pos) AS result
FROM cte;
```

Output:

```
"{10,6,0,3,13}"
```

**EDIT:**

As [`@a_horse_with_no_name`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name) proposed in comment you could use `unnest with ordinality`:

> If the **WITH ORDINALITY** clause is specified, an additional column of
>   type bigint will be added to the function result columns. This column
>   numbers the rows of the function result set, starting from 1.

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT pos, SUM(val::int) AS val
  FROM table_x
   ,LATERAL unnest(counts) with ordinality AS sub(val, pos)
  WHERE pos BETWEEN 2 AND 6
  GROUP BY pos
)
SELECT array_agg(val ORDER BY pos)
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Using `unnest(counts) with ordinality` would be more flexible